# Hover effects on text do not work when I use a href around img tags

Tags: image, hyperlink, attributes, hover, effects

So I have a html code which I want to perform in such a way that when I hover over the image, the text on its right moves further rightwards, and the image pops up. Additionally, I want only the image to act as a hyperlink. However, I'm not being able to do so.
Could somebody please check it, I am quite a beginner and know the least about html and css.

This the the code before:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <style>

.movetext{
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 260px;
    width: 500px;
    transition: 350ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    font-family: 'Lexend', sans-serif;

}

p {

    margin-top: -5px;
    
}

h1 {
    padding-bottom: -50px;
    font-size: 37px;
    font-weight: normal;
}


#wrapper {

  width: 100%;


}

.pop_up{
perspective: 250px;

width: 290px;
margin-left: ;
}

.pop_up img {
  transition: 350ms;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-radius: 17%;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}


.pop_up img:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0px,0px,20px);  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
  }


.image:hover ~ .movetext{
  transform: translateX(50px);
}


   </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="pop_up">
    <img class= "image" style="float:left;width:240px;height:200px;padding: 7px;object-fit: cover;object-position: 0 35%;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Open-book-2.svg" alt="Journals"></img>

    <div class="movetext"><h1>Journals</h1>
    <p>This is a list of journals</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9raq1dv8/

However, when I include a href tag around img tag, the hover effects do not work and the text does not move further rightwards, as in the code below.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ugn2x5ok/2/